# calculate time difference in HH:mm using keyup in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, time

there are 6 input fields out off which 5 input boxes will be filled with time and the result must come on to the 6th input box.
html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="time" id="start" name="logintime"/>
<input type="time" id="end"name="logouttime" />
<input type="time" id="lunch" name="lunch" />
<input type="time" id="startafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogin"/>
<input type="time" id="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout"/>
<input id="totalTime" readonly="readonly" />
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $time1 = $("#start");
var $time2 = $("#end");
var $time3 = $("#lunch");
var $time4 = $("#startafterlunch");
var $time5 = $("#endafterlunch");
var $diff = $("#totalTime");

function updateHours(){   

    var dtStart = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time1.val());
    var dtEnd = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time2.val());
    var dtLunch= new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time3.val());
    var dtStartafterlunch = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time4.val());
    var dtEndafterlunch = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time5.val());


    var diff = (dtEnd - dtStart)+(dtEndafterlunch-dtStartafterlunch);

    $diff.val(diff/1000);
  }
$time1.add($time2).on("change, keyup", function(){
    if($time1.val() && $time2.val()){
        updateHours()
    }
});

});
```

I took the code from an example of adding two time. but i dont know in the keyup how to add the other three time's and the result in the 6th box is in secs, I want to make it as HH:mm. Please help.
Thanks!!

Comment: difference between which date input  ?

Comment: any date! I just want to calculate the time difference

Comment: no... there is only one date with different times... starttime, endtime lunch and then again starttimeafterlunch and endtimeafterlunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $time1 = $("#start");
    var $time2 = $("#end");
    var $time3 = $("#lunch");
    var $time4 = $("#startafterlunch");
    var $time5 = $("#endafterlunch");
    var $diff = $("#totalTime");

    function updateHours(){   

        var dtStart = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time1.val());
        var dtEnd = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time2.val());
        var dtLunch= new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time3.val());
        var dtStartafterlunch = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time4.val());
        var dtEndafterlunch = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time5.val());

        var diff = ((dtEnd - dtStart)+(dtEndafterlunch-dtStartafterlunch)) / 1000;

        var hours = parseInt( diff / 3600 ) % 24;
        var minutes = parseInt( diff / 60 ) % 60;
        var seconds = diff % 60;

        var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);

        $diff.val(result);
    }

    $("#start, #end, #lunch, #startafterlunch, #endafterlunch, #totalTime").on("change, keyup", function(){
        if($time1.val() && $time2.val() && $time4.val() && $time5.val()){
            updateHours();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to calculate if the hours are more than 8:00 hours it must go it overtime input field and show the remaining hours ... please

Comment: Instead of putting the date manually can we put date dynamically and how?

Comment: Thanks a ot @Blaž Oražem...
I need one more small favour instead of putting "7/20/2015 " i want to enter date dynamically  keeping one more input date field in the html...  date will be same for all the time fields. Please help me in this.

Comment: Thank you so much... :) :) @Blaž Oražem

Comment: If I want to repeat the same fields 5 or 6 times in a html table as rows then its not Showing the total and overtime answers... its giving it only for the first row... what I must do to get the others answers?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate difference in HH:mm format:

```
var d1 = new Date(2025, 10, 28, 10, 25, 48, 498);
var d2 = new Date(2025, 10, 28, 12, 28, 32, 500);
var diff = d2 - d1; // it is difference in milliseconds

var totalHours = 1.0 * diff / 1000 / 60 / 60;
var hours = Math.floor(totalHours);
var minutes = Math.floor((totalHours - hours) * 60);

if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;

console.log(hours + ":" + minutes);
```